# Gitlab CI pipeline runs on normal push despite ‘only: merge_requests’ tag

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm trying to limit my Gitlab CI to run on merge requests, not on every push. Here's the structure of my yml file:

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/myproject/myimage

stages:
    - test

unit_tests:
    stage: test
    before_script: 
        - ...
    script:
        - make unit_tests
        - ./unit_tests
    only:
        - merge_requests
```

I.e. I have only a single job with the `merge_requests` specified. Still, the pipeline is run on every push to gitlab, without any merge request involved. What am I missing?

EDIT: I'm using Gitlab on the web, GitLab Enterprise Edition 12.3.0-pre, and Gitlab runners 12.3.0

Comment: What's your version of gitlab ? Check also the [requirements and limitations](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/merge_request_pipelines/#requirements-and-limitations) section (gitlab runner must be 11.9 or higher)

Comment: Edited post with that info

Comment: It works using the `.gitlab-ci.yml` you copied. I see a `Detached merge request pipeline` in the screen the MR. No pipeline is triggered if no MR.

Comment: Hm, that's odd. I also get the detached for MRs (marked in blue if I look at pipelines in the CI/CD tab), but in addition to other ones run on every push. Not sure what to do then...